# How to update ffmpeg sequence header?

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming, rtmp

I use the ffmpeg to stream the rtmp packets. Now, i need to change the bitrate dynamically , so is there any way to update the sequence header ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bitrate is not encoded into the sequence header. Hence no need to update it when changing bitrates.

Comment: In fact, i need update the sequence header. Thus, the player can show the right parameter.

Comment: I think you need to understand what the sequence header is. The sequence header is the AVC SPS/PPS NALUs. (unless we are talking AAC in which case it is the mpeg Audio Specific Config) SPS/PPS do not encode bitrate. So while you many need to update SOMETHING, it is certainly not the sequence header. If you are thinking about the onMetadata tag. It is not part of the sequence header. The bitrate IS encoded there, but most decoders ignore it.

Comment: Yes, i thought the sequence header includes bitrate. Thanks for your help to understand it. That is to say, i just need to update the metadata tag with the bitrate, right ? Because our player will show the bitrate value, and i should ensure the value is the right one.

Comment: You don't need to update onMetadata either since it's optional to begin with. Just start streaming at the new bitrate.

Comment: But the player can't show the right bitrate. I want to notify the change to the player.

Comment: No, you don't need to notify the player. It will figure it out. Players assume everything is variable bit rate.

Comment: I had tried that change the codec bitrate, but not notified the player. In this case, the quality of the streaming was good, but the player shown the original bitrate value.

Comment: Then it's a bug in the player. I would fix it there. You can try to send another onMetadata, but this is player specific issue, so no guarantee it will work.

Comment: Thanks. If you can provide some links about basic concepts of encode/decode or streaming, such as SPS/PPS/Sequence header, that will be great.

Comment: Take a look at my other stack overflow answers

Comment: Thanks. I think i need to understand the basic concept first.